# 1 line. Where to place ID in the link

Tags: php, jquery, hyperlink

I have created a separate posting from the large one of before because I think to have isolated the cause of the ID value not getting passed.

I have this link, but there is something not fully correct and no value is sent.

```
$sOutput .= '"<a href=\"#' ."id=" .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';
```

That above is the line of interest.

And for curiosity, this is the snippet which receives the value

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.flip').live('click',function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    $('#reviews').load('SendIdToDatabase.php', {idCruise: this.id});
     });
});

</script>
```

So, the whole scenario is:

A table, rows and links on a column in the rows.

When you click on the link, 2 things should happen.

a) A slide panel is opened

b) and the value is passed to a DIV inside that panel (div which loads the result of a php query which received that ID value)

but like I said, it is expected that only the Link needs to be tweaked

thanks a million

Alvaro

UPDATE

Well, 2 links have been proposed. None of them works.

This link allows the Slide Panel to open but it does not populate the div inside it

```
$sOutput .= '"<a href=\"#\"' .' id=\"' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';
```

And this link seems to do just the opposite. The slide wont open but the div seems to be loading info but I cant see it because the slide, like I said, doesnt open

```
$sOutput .= '"<a href=\"?id=' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" id=\"' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';
```

So, the goal is to get 1 Line that can make both things happening. Open the slide, and populate the div. Of course, using the JQUERY snippet shown

Comment: What HTML does your browser show when you inspect the link in firebug or a similar tool?

Comment: Is it just `id_cruise` vs `idCruise`?

Comment: can re-check ? seems like some opening single quote does not close properly

Comment: To make your life easier, you can start with putting pure variables, such as `$something = addslashes(...); echo "<a href=\"#\" id=\"{$something}\" ...` that is more for readability and less error prone.

Comment: Yes, well, I would not know where to make chunks out of it. Aside from that, someone said that ID is actually a separate entity and not part of the a href. He is right, but still, ...Rather than making variables out of it, just space them out as far as the screen reaches so that making out dots and quotes is easier

Answer (score 3):

Alvaro,
It seems to me your link building code is incorrect, ie

```
$sOutput .= '"<a href=\"#' ."id=" .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';
```

would echo to the screen

```
<a href="#id=id_cruise" class="flip">from_country</a>
```

Your HTML code is wrong, in that you haven't closed off the href and your browser thinks the href is href="#id=id_cruise" instead of your what I think you are trying to do

```
 $sOutput .= '"<a href=\"#\"' .' id=\"' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';
```

which should echo out the correctly formed HTML like this:

```
<a href="#" id="id_cruise" class="flip">from_country</a>
```

Now your href & id attributes are correctly formed, jQuery should be able to play nicely.

Cheers, J.

Comment: Thank you. Now, it truly looks very sound and clean. However, when I hover now down the rows with the cursor of the mouse, I dont see what I saw before, the changing of the id value in the status bar it just shows this

localhost/site/asfssf.php#   that is all and of course, no value is sent. hmm, dont know but surely is very close

Comment: Alvaro, if I understand correctly it sounds like you are trying pass the cruise id in the as a paramater in the URL? If so, just change it to $sOutput .= '"<a href=\"?id=' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\" id=\"' .addslashes($aRow['id_cruise']) .'\"  class=\"flip\">'.addslashes($aRow['from_country']).'</a>",';

Comment: Alvaro, the code I posted in the comment above does not have a hash (#) symbol in it, and it does have the equal (=) signs in the code. I think you need to recheck your code.